# Adding a count column for a filtered relationship to a select with a subquery in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, subquery

Suppose I have a Laravel 5.5 app with four models:

`Class`, `Student`, `Assignment` and `AssignmentSubmission`

A `Class` belongs to many `Students`, a `Student` belongs to many `Classes` and an `AssignmentSubmission` belongs to an `Assignment`, a `User`, and a `Class`.

So the tables look like this:

```
classes:
  id
  name

students:
  id
  name

class_student:
  class_id
  student_id

assignments:
  id
  name

assignment_submissions:
  id
  class_id
  student_id
  assignment_id
```

Now, in a query builder class I need to construct a query that returns the `Students` that belong to a `Class` with an extra column called `total_assignment_submissions` with a tally of how many assignments that student has submitted for **that class only**.

My first port of call was the following:

```php
$class->students()->withCount('assignmentSubmissions')->get();
```

But that returns the total assignment submissions for that student for all classes.

The following mySql query returns the right data:

```sql
SELECT *,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   `assignment_submission`
        WHERE  `student_id` = `students`.`id`
               AND `class_id` = ?) AS total_assignment_submissions
FROM   `students`
       INNER JOIN `class_student`
               ON `students`.`id` = `class_student`.`student_id`
WHERE  `class_student`.`class_id` = ?
```

But I can't seem to get the `selectSub()` `addSelect()` and `raw()` calls in the right order to get what I want. It seems that I only do it with raw queries but the event id will be unsanitized or otherwise I can do it but it only returns the `assignment_count` field and not the rest of the fields for the `student`.

```php
$class->students()
    ->selectSub(
        AssignmentSubmission::selectRaw('count(*)')
            ->whereClassId($class->id)->getQuery(), 
            'total_assignment_submissions'
    )->toSql();
```

There must be a way to do this. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withCount()` can be constrained.

```
$class->students()->withCount(['assignmentSubmissions' => function($q) use($course_id){
    $q->where('course_id', $course_id);
}])->get();
```

This will limit the count to that particular course.